# How to propagate uncertainty to $\tan(x)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

As a lab assignment I have to replicate experiment with spring oscillations, and eventually calculate spring constant. The measurements I took are: spring displacement from equilibrium $x$, mass of weights $m$, and period $T$. And presumed uncertainties: $\Delta_\alpha(x)=1[mm]$, $\Delta_e(x)=2[mm]$,  $\Delta_\alpha(t)=0.1[s]$,  $\Delta_e(t)=1[s]$. Where $\alpha$ stands for uncertainty of used equipment, and $e$ is readings uncertainty made by me. 
I calculated the standard uncertainty using this formula:
$$\sqrt\frac{\Delta_\alpha(x)^2+\Delta_e(x)^2}{3}$$
Which produced $u(x)=1.29[mm]$. Then using the following substitutions: 
$$F=kx$$
$$mg=kx$$
$$x=\frac{g}{k}m$$
I assert that: 
$$tan(a)=\frac{g}{k}$$ 
Because in this part of experiment I plotted $x=f(m)$, using excel's linest, I get the slope $s$ 
$$tan(a)=\frac{g}{k}=s$$ 
Now, my question is, since I had uncertainty for $x$ introduced, and it is used to compute $tan(a)$, then the latter is affected and should have uncertainty of itself? How in this case should I go about propagating uncertainty to $tan(a)$?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to propagate uncertainty through a trig function is to use the expression for general error propagation of an arbitrary function. It's quite easy, actually...

For any function

$g(X)$,

where $X$ is a set of $n$ parameters

$X = \{x_1, x_2,... x_n\}$

the relative uncertainty in $g(X)$ depends on the error in each parameter $x_i$ via the following form:

$\dfrac{\delta g(X)}{g(X)} = \sqrt{\left( \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}\cdot\dfrac{\delta x_1}{x_1}\right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_2}\cdot\dfrac{\delta x_2}{x_2}\right)^2 + ... \left( \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}\cdot\dfrac{\delta x_n}{x_n}\right)^2}$

$ = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}\cdot\dfrac{\delta x_i}{x_i}\right)^2}$

So, in your case, it is simply

$\dfrac{\delta \tan(a)}{\tan(a)} = \sqrt{\left( \dfrac{\partial \tan(a)}{\partial a}\cdot\dfrac{\delta a}{a} \right)^2}$

where of course

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = \sec^2(x)$,

and you should calculate $\delta a$ using the standard rules of error propegation.

EDIT: Sorry, I just realized my notation is different than yours... note that $\delta x = \Delta x$, going from my notation to yours. Let me know if any of this is beyond your knowledge level.

EDIT 2: Everything I said above is correct, but may not actually pertain to your issue at all. Why are you asserting $tan(a) = g/k$? I can't think of any reason that a tangent function should appear anywhere in the context of this experiment.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, for δa, a is arctan of my tan function?

Comment: @Michael.P Wait, I'm sorry, I answered your question too hastily; where is this tangent function even coming from..? Why do you assert $tan(a) = g/k$? Why can't you just solve the spring constant as $mg/x = k$, and propagate the error through that?

Comment: Also your formula for uncertainty in $x$ doesn't make sense. Why are you dividing by 3?

Comment: $x=\frac{x}{k}m+0$ is a line equation, y=ax+b. From which it flows that $\frac{x}{k}=tan(\alpha)$. As for why I did not go with mg/x=k, I have no idea

Comment: the formula was outlined in a physics scipt

Comment: I have to use tangent because I have multiple measurments of X and m, which are then "processed" with linear regression to obtain a trend line.

Comment: @jphollwed I usually use the general error propagation formula with absolute uncertainties rather than relative uncertainties, so I'm not used to seeing the formula as you wrote it. I'm having trouble seeing how the units work out. Each term under the radical appears to have units of $g/x_i$ (before squaring), and if the units of the parameters $x_i$ are not the same, then it does not seem valid to add the terms.

Comment: @Michael.P I'm sorry but I don't understand; tangent functions should enter nowhere into linear regression of some simple data like this. Can you link a source which told you to use that?